# TableView With 3 Sections and cells crashing

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift2

I have a simple `UITableViewController` with 3 sections and each section has 3 rows. I have already allocated each `cell` it's `reuse identifier`.
When I run the code, I get an `EXE_BAD_INSTRUCTION` error at return `cell`.

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class settingsViewController: UITableViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {


    return 3
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return 3
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell : UITableViewCell!

    if indexPath.section == 1
    {
        if indexPath.row == 1
        {

            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("draftCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        }

        else if indexPath.row == 0
        {
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("profileCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell




        }

        else if indexPath.row == 2
        {

            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("logoutCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell



        }






    }
    else if indexPath.section == 2{

        if indexPath.row == 0
        {



            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("facebookCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        }


        else if indexPath.row == 1
        {


            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("twitterCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell


        }


        else if indexPath.row == 2
        {
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("rateusCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        }



    }



    else if indexPath.section == 3
    {

        if indexPath.row == 0
        {


            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("creditsCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        }



        else if indexPath.row == 1
        {

            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("contactusCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        }


        else if indexPath.row == 2
        {


            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("termsandconditionsCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        }


    }


    return cell


}
```

Comment: are you payed for the amout of empty lines?

Answer (score 0):

For section number 0 you haven't written cellForRowAtIndexPath. You have given number of sections = 3, so its index starts from 0,

Correct your indexpath.section comparison i.e do it for indexpath.section == 0, indexpath.section == 1 and indexpath.section == 2.

Also you haven't registered class for tableview cell like

```
self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
```

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off using a static tableView in storyboard, instead of trying to programmatically code static cells in an dynamic tableView.

Apple's [Table View Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html) recommends:

> Use static cells to design a table with a fixed number of rows, each with its own layout. Use static cells when you know what the table looks like at design time, regardless of the specific information it displays.

*If you are determined to dynamically handle this, your code would be easier to read and maintain if you used a switch statement, instead of nested ifs.*

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 sections but the index should start from 0 (0,1,2,3,...). So modify your code starting from `indexPath.section == 0` (which is the first section of your table). Furthermore I agree with PetahChristian that you may use static cell to design your table.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

var cell : UITableViewCell!

if indexPath.section == 0
{
    if indexPath.row == 1
    {

        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("draftCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    }

    else if indexPath.row == 0
    {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("profileCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell




    }

    else if indexPath.row == 2
    {

        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("logoutCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell



    }






}
else if indexPath.section == 1{

    if indexPath.row == 0
    {



        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("facebookCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    }


    else if indexPath.row == 1
    {


        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("twitterCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell


    }


    else if indexPath.row == 2
    {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("rateusCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    }



}



else if indexPath.section == 2
{

    if indexPath.row == 0
    {


        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("creditsCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    }



    else if indexPath.row == 1
    {

        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("contactusCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    }


    else if indexPath.row == 2
    {


        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("termsandconditionsCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    }

}

return cell
}
```